# Why does Timmy Turner have more than 1 Fairy Godparent?

Tags: the-fairly-oddparents

Why does Timmy Turner have more than 1 Fairy Godparent? Other kids on the show seem to have only one Fairy Godparent (i.e. Remy Buxaplenty), but somehow Timmy Turner has 2: Cosmo & Wanda

> and later on he has 3, including Poof

Comment: Later on in the series he technically has 3 due to the child Cosmo and Wanda end up having.

Comment: @TylerShads indeed, see the spoiler text...

Answer (score 5):

Cosmo and Wanda are husband and wife. I guess they just keep married couples together. Otherwise they would probably almost never see each other, since fairies need to stay with their kid basically all the time unless specifically told otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

It's because Cosmo and Wanda are married so they are assigned to be fairy god parents together. And if you haven't notice Cosmo's hair is green and his eye color and he always turn into green things or animals the same for Wanda and pink and I've always known as pink and green a perfect match so yea.

Comment: Please don't be rude to other people in your answers. The first rule of Stack Exchange is "Be Nice". Also, I'm not sure why the green/pink thing applies to why he has two.

Answer (score -3):

The answer to this is that Timmy gets two because his fairies are husband and wife and can’t be apart from each other because if they do get parted from each other then they will only get to see each other in fairy world or when one of them sneaks away to see the each other.

Comment: What does this add to the answer posted 5 years ago which seems to say the exact same things?